# Grant access to action to role

Tags: zend-framework, acl

I want to grant access for specific action. I have module: privilegs, model: privilege, action: index and manage.

I make like this

```
class My_ACL extends Zend_Acl {

    public function __construct() {

    $this->addRole(new Zend_Acl_Role('admin'));

    $this->add(new Zend_Acl_Resource('discussions'))
            ->add(new Zend_Acl_Resource("privileges"))
          ->add(new Zend_Acl_Resource('privileges:privilege:index'));
           // another way for adding actions.
        //  ->add(new Zend_Acl_Resource('privileges:privilege',array('index','manage'));

         $this->allow('admin', 'account')
         ->allow('admin', 'privileges:privilege'); 
        }
    }
```

When I make like this, the index and manage actions are not working ?!

Answer (score 0):

Your ACL isn't automatically tied directly to you controllers / actions. You'd need to set it up that way, if that's how you want it.

So somewhere in your request (possibly as a plugin) you'd need to test if the current logged in user has access to your defined resource, and if not, do something...

```
if(!$acl->isAllowed($users_role, $resource_they_want_to_access))
{
     // go away, display access denied page etc
}
```